# Swift get difference between two dates in GMT

Tags: swift, datetime

I recently noticed strange behaviour trying to find the difference between two dates (in seconds).

I have a datestring that is in GMT time:

```
2016-01-07 01:09:47.289000
```

I want to find how many seconds since that time NOW.

But I notice that when I use NSDate() I get the time of my local time, not GMT time.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: All dates are GMT they don't have a timezone

Comment: That's what I thought. But if I do NSDate() I don't get the GMT time. At least it appears I am getting my local time in the Playground.

Comment: You can use NSDate().descriptionWithLocale(whatever) or use date formatter to display local time

Comment: Just use yourDate.timeIntervalSinceNow

Comment: Between 2 dates date1.timeIntervalSinceDate(date2)

Comment: Ohh. I think timeIntervalSinceNow will work! Thanks :)

Comment: Just invert it using NSDate()  at the front

Comment: Or just use abs() method

Comment: Past it is always negative

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34457607/edit

Answer (score 0):

Use the NStimeZone class to set time zone

```
let date = NSDate()
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
let gmt = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
formatter.timeZone = gmt
formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

To compare, convert the current date from NSDate to "GMT" and then calculate the time interval between the two.